# Knockout JS: how to update a whole observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I need a little help with Knockout JS.

I have a todo-list type web-app and I need to update on demand the whole observable array which contain the task list with data fetched from the database.

I have created a sample fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ingro/43XcU/26/

```
self.update = function(){

    var values = [
        {time: "17:00", title: "test#11"},
        {time: "18:00", title: "work#22"},     
        {time: "19:00", title: "task#33"},    
        {time: "20:00", title: "sleep#14"}
    ];

    self.clone = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap( values , function( clone) {
        return new Post(clone.time, clone.title);
    }));

    var count = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.posts(), function(post) {
        post.time(self.clone()[count].time());
        post.title(self.clone()[count].title());
        count++;
    });           

}
```

Data in "values" simulate a JSON response from the server. The only way I made it work is creating a clone observable array and then cycle through the real one and update all its elements one by one with the new values. This isn't an optimal solution for many reasons, for example if the number of elements in the two arrays are not equal and so on.

So anyone can suggest me a better way to update it?

Thanks and sorry for my awful english :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's absolutly what you need but I did it by using the knockout mapping plugin:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

You can try the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chubyone/a682w/6/

Regards.

Comment: Excuse me, I just got blocked again... and what if I want to update just one element, let's say the second one?

Comment: Ive updated the fiddle to find a way: http://jsfiddle.net/Chubyone/a682w/9/ . Ive removed somethings like the Post constructor and let the mapping plugin doing the full job. Created a new method to considere you want Save all, or only update one. So you can Run: click Update: the 2# is updated. Re-Run, click Save: array is changed ; then click Update: the first one (08:00) is updated. The postmapping helps us to find the corresponding element in the mapped collection. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, it's just what I needed! The only downside it's a little mapping meta-data inside the updated element... I wonder if I can get rid of it after the updated is completed, but I guess I can live with it :) Thank again, you are very helpful :)

Comment: There's a part in the doc concerning adding new property: "Including certain properties using “include”

When converting your view model back to a JS object, by default the mapping plugin will only include properties that were part of your original view model,[..] However, you can choose to customize this array:" 
var mapping = {
    'include': ["propertyToInclude", "alsoIncludeThis"]
}

May be this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll look at that asap! :D